# Tensorflow Object-detection API : How can i convert output to voice if there is multiple same objects in a frame?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to convert the detected objects in to voice. I could convert to voice by using the detected class names, but how can I know if there is multiple same objects in a frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by implementing an array.

when you detect the class name and convert it into voice, add that class name in an array when detecting the next object and check whether the class name already exists in the array or not, if it does it means u need to skip the voice conversion.

Comment: I have arleady done that but what if there is two same objects detected in a single frame.both has same clsssname and the second object wont append in to the array.hiw cani i solve this

Comment: As mentioned above, if the second object won't append in the array, you have detected multiple objects of the same class. Isn't that what you wanted?